# How can I fill remaining space but have minimum height in a flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal is to show the `header` and `div` in the current window height, leaving the `footer` hidden until the user scrolls.

I am trying to figure out a way to make `div` have a minimum height, so that the footer starts to show. However, when I do this the `footer` ends up going overtop of my `div`.

How can I give my `div` a minimum height but still make sure that the content doesn't overlap each other?

As you can see, footer goes over top of div.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  border:1px solid red;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color:blue;
}

div {
  background-color:#eee;
  flex: 1;
  min-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>header</header>
  <div>content</div>
</section>

<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean: The code you posted works the way you describe it as desired output. (detail improvement suggestion: Add `margin: 0` to `html, body` to avoid the default margin of the browser, also its being added to the 100% height.) But what is your actual problem?

Comment: @Johannes I've edited the code sample in my question to include minimum height. You can see that when the window heigh is small, the footer overlaps the content and loses it's background color.

Comment: But what do you need the min-height for - the 100% height of the section is sufficient for your desired result and provides a min-height in another way?

Comment: I need the min height because the content that will be inside the div will not look good if the window height reaches a certain threshold. So it cannot, for example, be smaller than 200px. @Johannes

Comment: So you want the div to take up remaining space but have a minimum height too? In that case we need to change the properties of the section container as it is currently overflowing the container. Giving the `<section>` a `min-height` instead of `height` can solve this problem, i've updated my answer below.

Comment: Okay, I undestand – it's strange behaviour, yes. I didn't find a solution which includes the 200px min-height for the div, but I created a workaround solution using a min-height for `body`, which I added as an answer below. I hop it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question and what you're trying to achieve.

You start saying you want the footer to be hidden until the user scrolls, which is what is already happening.

Then you say you want the start of the footer to show but without overlapping the div? In that case just make the height of the `<section>` less than 100%, otherwise there is no way to view the footer without it overlapping your `div` content.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  border:1px solid red;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color:blue;
}

div {
  background-color:#eee;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>header</header>
  <div>
    <span>content top</span>
    <span>content bottom</span> 
  </div>
</section>

<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: I want the footer to be hidden, unless the div reaches a min-height. In which case It's fine that the footer shows. But I can't get min-height to work without the footer overlapping on top of my div. (I've edited the question with a reproducible)

Comment: Perfection. Thank you! I found that you did not need z-index. Why did you add it?

Comment: You don't need it, was added accidentally, will remove from the answer. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few things that came to my mind, but haven't found a solution that contains the 200px min-height for the `div`. However, as a workaround, you could apply a min-height to `body`, with a value that approximately equals 200px plus the height of header and footer. I used 240px in my snippet below, but you can adjust that value as needed. At least *that* way you don't get that overlap of the footer.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 240px;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  border:1px solid red;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color:blue;
}

div {
  background-color:#eee;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>header</header>
  <div>content</div>
</section>

<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  background-color: #eee;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: calc(100vh - (header + footer));
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* adjust this value to match the height of your footer */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>header</header>
  <div>content</div>
</section>

<footer>footer</footer>
```